# How to localize model field names without [Display] attribute?

Tags: validation, localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have implemented localization for validation attributes using IValidationMetadataProvider approach.

It uses field names of the model in the error messages.

I would like to translate the field names from resource strings, the same way as I do for the messages. But I don't want to put `[Display("FieldName")]` attribute on every field. There's no need to put even empty `[Display]` attribute - it would be redundant boilerplate code.

Ideally, I'd like to somehow tell the MVC validator that every time it needs field name for validation message, it should ask some custom provider for it, so I can return the value from my IStringLocalizer implementation.

Is there any way to feed custom field names into MVC validator without spitting `[Display]` attribute everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trial and error and also looking for reflection-based DisplayAttribute injection, I found that it's possible to inject my own IDisplayMetadataProvider.

So, now I can omit [Display] attribute completely and my class will automatically extract field names from resources, matching model property names. Additional bonus - it will ensure consistent names for matching properties because it will use the global default values unless explicit `[Display(Name = "SomeOtherResourceKey")]` is applied on a specific property.

```
public class LocalizableInjectingDisplayNameProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
    {
        private IStringLocalizer _stringLocalizer;
        private Type _injectableType;

        public LocalizableInjectingDisplayNameProvider(IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer, Type injectableType)
        {
            _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;
            _injectableType = injectableType;
        }

        public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
            // ignore non-properties and types that do not match some model base type
            if (context.Key.ContainerType == null || 
                !_injectableType.IsAssignableFrom(context.Key.ContainerType))
                return;

            // In the code below I assume that expected use of field name will be:
            // 1 - [Display] or Name not set when it is ok to fill with the default translation from the resource file
            // 2 - [Display(Name = x)]set to a specific key in the resources file to override my defaults

            var propertyName = context.Key.Name;
            var modelName = context.Key.ContainerType.Name;

            // sanity check 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName))
                return;

            var fallbackName = propertyName + "_FieldName";
            // If explicit name is missing, will try to fall back to generic widely known field name,
            // which should exist in resources (such as "Name_FieldName", "Id_FieldName", "Version_FieldName", "DateCreated_FieldName" ...)

            var name = fallbackName;

            // If Display attribute was given, use the last of it
            // to extract the name to use as resource key
            foreach (var attribute in context.PropertyAttributes)
            {
                var tAttr = attribute as DisplayAttribute;
                if (tAttr != null)
                {
                    // Treat Display.Name as resource name, if it's set,
                    // otherwise assume default. 
                    name = tAttr.Name ?? fallbackName;
                }
            }

            // At first, attempt to retrieve model specific text
            var localized = _stringLocalizer[name];

            // Final attempt - default name from property alone
            if (localized.ResourceNotFound)
                localized = _stringLocalizer[fallbackName];

            // If not found yet, then give up, leave initially determined name as it is
            var text = localized.ResourceNotFound ? name : localized;

            context.DisplayMetadata.DisplayName = () => text;
        }

    }
```